# C++ WINAPI Shared memory dynamic arrays

Tags: c++

I'm trying to share an array of structs containing 2 dynamic arrays using shared memory to use the structs in another process. So far I can share an array of structs but these do not contain dynamic arrays yet. Any help on completing this problem would be great.

Expected:

```
typedef struct {
    int id;
    int type;
    int count;
    int[] values;
    int[] settings;
} Entry;
```

Current code:

```
typedef struct {
    int id;
    int type;
    int count;
} Entry;

BOOL DumpEntries(TCHAR* memName) {
     int size = entries.size() * sizeof(Entry) + sizeof(DWORD);

     ::hMapObject = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, size, memName);
     if (::hMapObject == NULL) {
          return FALSE;
     }

     ::vMapData = MapViewOfFile(::hMapObject, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, size);
     if (::vMapData == NULL) {
          CloseHandle(::hMapObject);
          return FALSE;
     }

     (*(DWORD*)::vMapData) = entries.size();
     Entry* eArray = (Entry*)(((DWORD*)::vMapData) + 1);
     for(int i = entries.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) eArray[i] = entries.at(i);

     UnmapViewOfFile(::vMapData);
     return TRUE;
}

BOOL ReadEntries(TCHAR* memName, Entry** entries, DWORD &number_of_entries) {
     HANDLE hMapFile = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, memName);
     if (hMapFile == NULL) {
          return FALSE;
     }

     DWORD *num_entries = (DWORD*)MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0);
     if (num_entries == NULL) {
          CloseHandle(hMapFile);
          return FALSE;
     }
     number_of_entries = *num_entries;

     if(number_of_entries == 0)
     {
         // special case: when no entries was found in buffer
         *entries = NULL;
         return true;
     }

     Entry* tmpEntries = (Entry*)(num_entries + 1);

     *entries = new Entry[*num_entries];

     for (UINT i = 0; i < *num_entries; i++) {
          (*entries)[i] = tmpEntries[i];
     }

     UnmapViewOfFile(num_entries);
     CloseHandle(hMapFile);

     return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Entry* tmpEntries = (Entry*)(num_entries + 1);

What are you trying to do here? Looks really suspicious. Why are you typecasting so much? I think you need to back away from this sort of complexity and learn C++ rules and conventions.

Comment: @TimStraubinger: "*What are you trying to do here? Looks really suspicious*" - it is normal pointer arithmetic.  `num_entries` is a pointer to a `DWORD`.  `num_entries+1` is the same as `&num_entries[1]`, which is the same as `((BYTE*)num_entries) + (sizeof(DWORD) * 1)`.  The code is getting the memory address that follows the `DWORD`, and then type-casting that address to `Entry*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass pointers across process boundaries, so you can't store pointers inside the `struct` items that you put in the shared memory.  What you can do is allocate the shared memory block itself to be large enough to hold all of the array data, and then use offsets to access the various arrays as needed, eg:

```
typedef struct
{
    int id;
    int type;
    int count;
    int *values;
    int *settings;
} Entry;

#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct
{
    int id;
    int type;
    int count;
    DWORD values_offset;
    DWORD values_count; // if different than 'int count'
    DWORD settings_offset;
    DWORD settings_count; // if different than 'int count' 
} SharedMemEntry;
#pragma pack(pop)

BOOL DumpEntries(TCHAR* memName)
{
    DWORD NumValues = 0;
    DWORD NumSettings = 0;

    // or whatever your container actually is...
    for(std::vector<Entry>::reverse_iterator iter = entries.rbegin();
        iter != entries.rend(); ++iter)
    {
        Entry &e = *iter;

        // or whatever you have to do to calculate how many
        // integers are in the values[] and settings[] arrays...
        //
        NumValues += e.count;
        NumSettings += e.count;
    }

    DWORD memsize = sizeof(DWORD) +
                    (entries.size() * sizeof(SharedMemEntry)) +
                    (sizeof(int) * NumValues) +
                    (sizeof(int) * NumSettings);

    if (hMapObject != NULL)
        CloseHandle(hMapObject);

    hMapObject = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, memsize, memName);
    if (hMapObject == NULL) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    BYTE *vMapData = (BYTE*) MapViewOfFile(hMapObject, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, memsize);
    if (vMapData == NULL) {
        CloseHandle(hMapObject);
        hMapObject = NULL;
        return FALSE;
    }

    DWORD *pEntryCount = (DWORD*) vMapData;
    *pEntryCount = entries.size();

    SharedMemEntry* pEntries = (SharedMemEntry*) (pEntryCount + 1);
    int *pValues = (int*) (pEntries + entries.size());
    int *pSettings = (int*) (pValues + NumValues);

    // or whatever your container actually is...
    for(std::vector<Entry>::reverse_iterator iter = entries.rbegin();
        iter != entries.rend(); ++iter)
    {
        Entry &e = *iter;
        SharedMemEntry &eEntry = *pEntries++;

        eEntry.id = e.id;
        eEntry.type = e.type;
        eEntry.count = e.count;

        eEntry.values_offset = ((BYTE*)pValues - vMapData);
        eEntry.values_count = e.count; // or whatever you need...
        for(DWORD k = 0; k < eEntry.values_count; ++k) {
            *pValues++ = e.values[k];
        }

        eEntry.settings_offset = ((BYTE*)pSettings - vMapData);
        eEntry.settings_count = e.count; // or whatever you need...
        for(DWORD k = 0; k < eEntry.settings_count; ++k) {
            *pSettings++ = e.settings[k];
        }
    }

    UnmapViewOfFile(vMapData);
    return TRUE;
}

BOOL ReadEntries(TCHAR* memName, Entry** entries, DWORD &num_entries)
{
    HANDLE hMapFile = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_READ, FALSE, memName);
    if (hMapFile == NULL) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    BYTE *vMapData = (BYTE*) MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);
    if (vMapData == NULL) {
        CloseHandle(hMapFile);
        return FALSE;
    }

    DWORD *pEntryCount = (DWORD*) vMapData;
    num_entries = *pEntryCount;

    if (num_entries == 0)
    {
        // special case: when no entries was found in buffer
        *entries = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        SharedMemEntry *pEntries = (SharedMemEntry*) (pEntryCount + 1);

        *entries = new Entry[num_entries];

        for (DWORD i = 0; i < num_entries; ++i)
        {
            Entry &e = (*entries)[i];
            SharedMemEntry &eEntry = pEntries[i];

            e.id = eEntry.id;
            e.type = eEntry.type;
            e.count = eEntry.count;

            e.values = new int[eEntry.values_count];
            e.settings = new int[eEntry.settings_count];

            int *pValues = (int*) (vMapData + eEntry.values_offset);
            for(DWORD j = 0; j < eEntry.values_count; ++j) {
                e.values[j] = pValues[j];
            }

            int *pSettings = (int*) (vMapData + eEntry.settings_offset);
            for(DWORD j = 0; j < eEntry.settings_count; ++j) {
                e.settings[j] = pSettings[j];
            }
        }
    }

    UnmapViewOfFile(vMapData);
    CloseHandle(hMapFile);

    return TRUE;
}
```

Alternatively, you should consider automating the memory management and loops instead of doing everything manually:

```
typedef struct
{
    int id;
    int type;
    int count;
    std::vector<int> values;
    std::vector<int> settings;
} Entry;

#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct
{
    int id;
    int type;
    int count;
    DWORD values_offset;
    DWORD values_count; // if different than 'int count'
    DWORD settings_offset;
    DWORD settings_count; // if different than 'int count' 
} SharedMemEntry;
#pragma pack(pop)

BOOL DumpEntries(TCHAR* memName)
{
    DWORD NumValues = 0;
    DWORD NumSettings = 0;

    // or whatever your container actually is...
    for(std::vector<Entry>::reverse_iterator iter = entries.rbegin();
        iter != entries.rend(); ++iter)
    {
        Entry &e = *iter;
        NumValues += e.values.size();
        NumSettings += e.settings.size();
    }

    DWORD memsize = sizeof(DWORD) +
                    (entries.size() * sizeof(SharedMemEntry)) +
                    (sizeof(int) * NumValues) +
                    (sizeof(int) * NumSettings);

    if (hMapObject != NULL)
        CloseHandle(hMapObject);

    hMapObject = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, memsize, memName);
    if (!hMapObject) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<void, decltype(&UnmapViewOfFile)> uMapData( MapViewOfFile(hMapObject, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, memsize), &UnmapViewOfFile );
    BYTE *vMapData = (BYTE*) uMapData.get();
    if (!vMapData) {
        CloseHandle(hMapObject);
        hMapObject = NULL;
        return FALSE;
    }

    DWORD *pEntryCount = (DWORD*) vMapData;
    *pEntryCount = entries.size();

    SharedMemEntry* pEntries = (SharedMemEntry*) (pEntryCount + 1);
    int *pValues = (int*) (pEntries + entries.size());
    int *pSettings = (int*) (pValues + NumValues);

    // or whatever your container actually is...
    for(std::vector<Entry>::reverse_iterator iter = entries.rbegin();
        iter != entries.rend(); ++iter)
    {
        Entry &e = *iter;
        SharedMemEntry &eEntry = *pEntries++;

        eEntry.id = e.id;
        eEntry.type = e.type;
        eEntry.count = e.count;

        eEntry.values_offset = ((BYTE*)pValues - vMapData);
        eEntry.values_count = e.values.size();
        pValues = std::copy(e.values.begin(), e.values.end(), pValues);

        eEntry.settings_offset = ((BYTE*)pSettings - vMapData);
        eEntry.settings_count = e.settings.size();
        pSettings = std::copy(e.settings.begin(), e.settings.end(), pSettings);
    }

    return TRUE;
}

// or whatever container type you want...
BOOL ReadEntries(TCHAR* memName, std::vector<Entry> &entries)
{
    entries.clear();

    std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<HANDLE>::type, decltype(&CloseHandle)> uMapFile( OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_READ, FALSE, memName), &CloseHandle );
    HANDLE hMapFile = uMapFile.get();
    if (!hMapFile) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<void, decltype(&UnmapViewOfFile)> uMapData( MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0), &UnmapViewOfFile );
    BYTE *vMapData = (BYTE*) uMapData.get();
    if (!vMapData) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    DWORD *pEntryCount = (DWORD*) vMapData;
    DWORD num_entries = *pEntryCount;

    if (num_entries != 0)
    {
        entries.resize(num_entries);

        SharedMemEntry *pEntries = (SharedMemEntry*) (pEntryCount + 1);

        for (DWORD i = 0; i < num_entries; ++i)
        {
            Entry &e = entries[i];
            SharedMemEntry &eEntry = pEntries[i];

            e.id = eEntry.id;
            e.type = eEntry.type;
            e.count = eEntry.count;

            e.values.reserve(eEntry.values_count);
            e.settings.reserve(eEntry.settings_count);

            int *pValues = (int*) (vMapData + eEntry.values_offset);
            std::copy(pValues, pValues + eEntry.values_count, std::back_inserter(e.values));

            int *pSettings = (int*) (vMapData + eEntry.settings_offset);
            std::copy(pSettings, pSettings + eEntry.settings_count, std::back_inserter(e.settings));
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Either way, make sure you provide some kind of synchronization between `DumpEntries()` and `ReadEntries()`, such as with shared events from `CreateEvent()`, so that `ReadEntries()` does not try to read from the memory while `DumpEntries()` is still writing to it, and vice versa.

Comment: flexible arrays are not valid in C++, allthough it seems possible if declaring `int values[1];` in the `Entry` struct and using `malloc` to allocate memory on both sides. Do you happen to know how to do this?

Comment: @MircoProgram dynamically allocate the arrays, or use `std::vector`

Comment: `std::vector` internally uses pointers so it's not wise to share those, right?

Comment: @MircoProgram: Correct. I wasn't suggesting using `std::vector` in the structures of the shared memory, only in the structures that are local to each app.

Comment: I tested using your code and writing to the memory seems to work, only upon reading I get a compile error on the line `Entry &e = entries[i];` (a reference of type 'Entry &' not const qualified cannot be initialized with a value of type 'Entry *') . I've changed it to `Entry* &e = entries[i];` but I'm getting a null pointer when trying to access the entries array.

Comment: @MircoProgram Sorry, it should be `Entry &e = (*entries)[i]; ` instead. I updated the example.

Comment: code works good, only one small problem. The values & settings array has the correct length but when assigning values (currently only one number '11') i get random values like 2798794, -65456. The way I'm assigning values is as following: `entry->settings = new int[size];
entry->values = new int[size];
model->settings[i] = 11;//in loop
model->values[i] = 11;`

Comment: @MircoProgram: what is `model` and how is it related to `entry`? You are not assigning anything to `entry->settings[i]` or `entry->values[i]`, unless `model` is pointing at `entry`.

Comment: I made a couple of typo fixes in `DumpEntries()` and now `ReadEntries()` gets the correct values.

Comment: Hey, I appreciate your hard effort in answering my question, however I'm not using C11 so smart pointers are not available. Do you seem to have a usage example of the first block of code? The application is closing without an error, I'm puzzled.

Comment: I fixed it myself, synchronization was not working as expected, thank you for all your help!